# How do I close all windows only in the current tab of vim

Tags: vim

I know that `:qa` closes all the buffers and windows and exits vim. It's also clear that I could use `:q` to quit a single window/split in a given tab. But consider the case where I have three windows in the current tab and a bunch of adjacent open tabs as well. I want to close the three windows in the current tab but not quit vim or the other adjacent tabs.

How do I do it? I went through the vim help file, but there doesn't seem to a direct option. I imagine it's possible to get such functionality using vimscript, but I want to be sure before drawing the conclusion that it's the only option.

If vim doesn't support it directly and someone has been awesome enough to write a plugin for it, I would love to know about it.

Comment: In Vim terminology a "split" = a "window". What do you mean by closing "all splits in the current window"? Are you talking about tab pages?

Comment: @glts yep, I realized soon after posting it that I mucked up the terminology. Fixing it now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Do you mean you want to close the current tab page?  Then there's the `:tabclose` command for that.

Comment: I figured it out around the same time you answered it. Thanks though.

Comment: How can I close the last tab page?

Comment: @HieuM.Nguyen Currently, you would have to know the tabnumber and specify that to `:tabclose`.  There's a [proposed patch](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.editors.vim.devel/46770) to enhance handling of `{count}` arguments to some related commands (`:close`, `:argadd`, `:argdelete`).  Might want to ask the author to include the relative offset handling to `:tabclose` so that `:$tabclose` works.

Comment: Thanks jamessan. My purpose was to bind a shortcut for closing a tabpage. I wrote a autocommand that alternate between `:tabclose` and `:q` depends on the current number of tab: `au TabEnter * let g:tabcount = tabpagenr('$') | if tabcount == 1 | nnoremap <leader>c :q<CR> | else | nnoremap <leader>c :tabclose<CR> |endif`

Comment: @HieuM.Nguyen It's probably simpler to use an [<expr>](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Amap-expression) mapping.  `nnoremap <expr> <leader>c tabpagenr('$') > 1 ? ':tabclose<CR>' : ':q<CR>'` seems to be a simpler way to do what you want.

Comment: Works like a charm. Short and effective!

Answer (score 5):

I also found out this command works. The help page at `help tabpage` was quite useful.

```
:tabc
```

Like @glts pointed out in a comment, I needed to get my vim terminology in order before I could find an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The existing answers which suggest `:tabc[lose]` are correct. However, there is one situation in which another answer may be useful.

In the case that you want to close the windows in the current tab to reduce the number of things you have open before opening a new tab and pulling some new files into it, the `tabclose` option still works; succinctly, you would do `:tabc|tabe`. However, the Vim purist in me can't help but point out that you could save yourself three keystrokes by typing `:on|ene` instead, which is short for `:only | enew`, or "close all windows except this one in the current tab; now, open a new unnamed file in this window." And if want to replace the current windows with a named file, this idiom is two more keystrokes shorter than the other, for a total of five: `:on|e foo.txt` versus `:tabc|tabe foo.txt`.

So while the generally correctly answer to the question is the `:tabclose` command, there are cases in which `:on|e` or `:on|ene` are more useful.